# Double query to Couchbase and Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, couchbase

I want a library that gives me the power to query in Couchbase and ElasticSearch simultaneously.

I want to make queries in both databases simultaneously
(preferablyjava )

Answer (score 0):

hello take a look for this :
https://github.com/koendeschacht/count-db
or 
https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni

Comment: thx but in this two git repo all the ops not included elasticsearch or couchbase